# Magento2 development and speed of compilation

Tags: magento2, frontend

I have a lot of experience working with both, Magento 1, as all front-end tools like less, grunt and so on.

But now working in Magento2 i have some concerns i've not been able to solve this weekend. I've been searching like crazy. I do hear many other developers experiencing the same.

The bottom line of the issue is. The site is slow. (10sec load times per page is not strange)

I walked through the entire devdocs of magento. 
But in production mode Magento re-generated the CSS and such. But this taks a huge amount of time. I used Vagrant and Digital ocean server. Even though Digital Ocean is quicker its not useable to develop on.

Whats the best way to proceed?

Comment: Do You say about speed of setup:di:compile command? if yes than why do You run it more then one?

Comment: Its not about the di:compile. For example, if i remove a part of the pub/static folder so it re-generates it takes a very long time to refresh the page since he compiles the new part of code right.

Answer (score 1):

I am also fronted developer and facing same problem, it's because of server side compilation mode.

Please try following method, may be it's helpful and you don't need grunt cmd also so it's save your time also

go to

```
store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Front-end development workflow
```

and change workflow type to **Client side less compilation**

Now go to your Magento installed directory and manually delete following folders

```
 1. pub\static\frontend\Magento  (remove all theme folders)

 2. var\ (remove all items)
```

now edit any less file and check it.

no need to run any **grunt CMD** direct Refresh your browser may be  it's working fine.

also please install below add-on in firefox

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/simonedeponti/?src=api

it's show you direct less file path in browser when you inspect elements.

I think it's better way to save time.

Comment: Its not really that. to be honest. is setup a php7 environment without Xdebug this solved a lot of speed issues. Also i set the mode to developer instead of default. this also gives some more speed. And last but not least kept a few cachings enabled instead of disabled... Further the first load after a clean is slow. but if everything is build it runs pretty o.k. now. Ok nog 1.5s load times but hey its in dev mode. in production its sick fast

Comment: thanks you for expending my knowledge, will check and get back to you with better solution.